# In Jasper iReport 4.5.0, how do I get the Label Mask on a chart to save?

Tags: jasper-reports, label, ireport, mask, stackedbarseries

I'm using iReport 4.5.0, which is so far more pleasurable than CF's buggy report builder... the problem is that some elements that I can set in the designer using the Properties side bar don't appear to write any XML, and hence don't save.

I'm using a stacked bar chart, which is basically a three variable graph, and the Value Axis Label Mask doesn't appear to save. My mask is "#.#%" (sans quotes) which converts the doubles into nice percentages and saves me the trouble of doing the conversion myself.

Does anyone know what the XML tag is for the Value Axis Tick Label Mask in a stacked bar chart? If I can set it in the XML, I'm sure it will stick...

Comment: Did you try changing the setting in the properties bar, press tab to go to next property. Then Click Save. Then look and see if the XML updated. I noticed sometimes the tabs get of sync, and I lose small changes like that. I would file a bug, but I have not been able to reproduce it consistently.

Comment: It previews just fine. I'll try the tabbing trick and see if it works. If one of you could tell me what the property is called, I'll export to a jxml file, make the change, and reimport.
I've noticed similar issues when changing the datasource on the XML side; it seems the XML and Designer tabs always sync, even on saves.

Comment: In theory it's not possible to preview correctly but save with something missing. iReport first saves and then generates the .jasper file from the saved .jrxml. I realize theories don't always work out, and you are surely seeing what you're describing. But it's hard to guess why. Try setting the mask in a brand new report to find it in the XML there.

Answer (score 0):

For multiaxes charts use:

```
<axis>

<!-- other XML tags here-->

   <valueAxisFormat>
      <axisFormat tickLabelMask="#.#%"/>
   </valueAxisFormat>
</axis>
```

For single axe chart use:

```
<linePlot>

<!-- other XML tags here-->

   <valueAxisFormat>
      <axisFormat tickLabelMask="#.#%"/>
   </valueAxisFormat>
</linePlot>
```